# Evaluate the determinant of a $3×3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Q.1 Evaluate the determinant of the following matrix

$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -75& 453\\ 0& N+1
&  -59\\ 0& 0& 2\end{pmatrix}$

I solved for $N$, as follows

$1((N+1)(2)-(-59)(0))-(-75)((0)(2)-(-59)(0))+453((0)(0)-N+1(0))$

= $1(2N+2)+75(0)+453(0)$

$2N=-2$

$N=-1$.

Now that I have $N$ do I sub that in for $N+1$ and then get the determinant of $A$? Or should I not have gone about it this way?

Comment: Incidentally, it seems like it's marginally easier to go down the leftmost column, rather than the topmost row. But only marginally. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of the diagonal entries (why?)

Hence $\det(A) =2(N+1) $

---

From where you get $2N=-2? $

Comment: so what I have done is incorrect?

Comment: So my answer is just simply det(A)=2N+2?

Comment: I don't understand why you put $2N=-2$ ?

Comment: It was a mistake! I set the set(A)=0 which I shouldn't have

Comment: @artefact191 yes. $\det(A) =2(N+1) $ . No further simplification is possible unless the value of $N$ is given.